# Effect size for marginal means of a model with an interaction term

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, lsmeans, cohens-d

I'm wondering what is the correct way to calculate the `eff_size()` of a `lmer` model with an interaction term. I'm following [this kind reply by Lenth](https://github.com/rvlenth/emmeans/issues/398#issuecomment-1412784639) and [the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/comparisons.html).

- I **can't** actually provide the data in this case. But the rationale is a repeated-measures design in which all participants have 4 `SCORE` on two `YEARS` on two `CONDITIONS` (C1, C2). The model is:

```
## Variables: 

# SCORE: Test scores 
# YEAR: 2021, 2022
# Condition: C1, C2

# No int
mod <- lmer(SCORE ~ YEAR + CONDITION + Age_z + (1 | ID), data = df) 

# With the interaction model
mod_int <- lmer(SCORE ~ YEAR * CONDITION + Age_z (1 | ID), data = df)
```

- I'm interested in the pairwise comparisons of Year x Condition. Namely =>

Condition:

C1 2021 X C2 2021 
C1 2022 X C2 2022

Year:

C1 2021 X C1 2022 
C2 2021 X C2 2022

- I'm wondering what is the correct approach for the model **with the interaction term**? I'm currently doing this:

```
### Estimating marginal means from a model with interaction terms ### 

## Estimating:

marginal_means <- emmeans(mod_int, ~ YEAR * CONDITION, 
                          lmer.df = "satterthwaite") 

## Pairwise comparisons

pmarginal_means <-  marginal_means %>%  pairs(adjust="Tukey", reverse = TRUE)

## Get effect size: 

### correctiong sigma and edf
### Look at VarCorr(mod1) and then compute sigma = sqrt((error SD)^2 + (subject SD)^2)
sigmaValues <- VarCorr(mod_int)
sigmaValues

sigma <- sqrt((6.2070)^2 + (2.5204)^2)

### calculate Cohen's d: # eff_size(emm1, sigma = sigma(mod1), edf = df.residual(mod1)) ### before: 

### check the lowest df from pmarginal_means

eff1 <- eff_size(marginal_means, 
                 sigma = sigma, 
                 edf = 229, # LOWER FROM pmarginal_means
                 method = "pairwise")
```

- My question is => is how do I calculate the correct pairwise tests that I need and then get the correct `eff_size()` ?